# Is it possible to view the tserver black list in YugabyteDB using the yb-admin tool?

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Trying to find a way to get the list of black-listed yb-tservers. Is there a command or an API that returns this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've added a server to the blacklist with [change_blacklist](https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/admin/yb-admin/#change-blacklist) command:

```
./bin/yb-admin --init_master_addrs localhost change_blacklist ADD 10.99.99.99:7100
```

You can use [get_universe_config](https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/admin/yb-admin/#get-universe-config) in yb-admin cli:

```
./bin/yb-admin --init_master_addrs localhost get_universe_config
{"version":1,"serverBlacklist":{"hosts":[{"host":"10.99.99.99","port":7100}],"initialReplicaLoad":0},"clusterUuid":"01f3ec0d-feef-4b39-8aeb-2c7229eba63e"}
```